# Estimability and less than full rank model matrices

Tags: multiple-regression, multicollinearity, lm

So I have some data...

```
> head(df)
          y  a   b   c  d   e  f     g
1  9.393915 No  No  No No Yes No WAW9H
2  9.936906 No  No  No No Yes No WAW9H
3  7.573025 No  No Yes No  No No WAW9H
4  9.123976 No Yes Yes No Yes No WAW9H
5 13.569253 No Yes  No No Yes No WAW9H
6 10.468927 No  No  No No Yes No WAW9H
```

and I fit this model...

> mod <- lm(y ~ a + b + c + d + e + f + g + a:g + b:g + c:g + d:g + e:g + f:g, data = df)

but some of the coefficients are NA:

```
> summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ a + b + c + d + e + f + g + a:g + b:g + c:g + 
d:g + e:g + f:g, data = df)

Residuals:
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-16.2662  -1.8112   0.0096   1.8455  28.3563 

Coefficients: (55 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   9.855044   0.128512  76.686  < 2e-16 ***
aYes          0.152247   0.341803   0.445 0.656016    
bYes          1.536731   0.156493   9.820  < 2e-16 ***
cYes          0.956878   0.130900   7.310 2.71e-13 ***
.
.
.
aYes:gBJK2U         NA         NA      NA       NA
```

I suppose it has to do with there not being enough data to estimate these coefficients (check out BJK2U)

```
> table(data.frame(df$a, df$g))
df.a  AS2CD BJK2U . . .
  No   2096     2 . . .    
  Yes    84     0 . . .
```

How do I fit a reduced model without these coefficients? How do I remove some of the levels of the factor g? The reason I want to do this is so that I don't get warnings when I call the predict() function on this model. I don't want to accidentally try to predict a non-estimable thing. Apologies for the lack of reproducibility in this example.

```
> levels(df$g)
 [1] "AS2CD" "BJK2U" "CAT2N" "CER"   "CG3N"  "CH2XF" "CMU5P" "CV7D"  "DDS2S" "DGP3A" "DRB5P" "DRG3E" "DTL4N" "EAR9W" "ES6T"  "GEM3M" "GRU6N" "JHM7Q" "JJA9H"
[20] "JPR5K" "JSH5N" "JSR7N" "MAK4Z" "MKW2Y" "MS7HA" "NPC8A" "PAR8B" "PRK5R" "RCR3E" "RDP5P" "REO4X" "RM5S"  "RR5WF" "RS5FG" "SAO4R" "SAS3K" "SDL4V" "SK7BQ"
[39] "TAS8N" "WAW9H" "WB4Z"
```

Comment: Taylor, could you proceed in this problem? Did you have any breakthrough here? It's a fascinating query, imo.